# How to resolve the dilemma when a factory needs to create objects with multiple common parameters?

Tags: java, factory-pattern, builder-pattern

I have a set of subclasses of `PageRenderer` abstract class, e.g.

- `ImagePageRenderer`
- `TextPageRenderer`
- `VideoPageRenderer`.

So in order to get the `PageRenderer` instance, a *factory method* is suitable. The `concreate` factory looks like this:

```
public class PageRendererFactory extends AbstractFactory {
  PageRenderer createPageRenderer(Type type) {
    //implementation
  }
}//Code AbstractFactory is skipped here
```

However, the problem is that the `PageRenderer` contains several instance variables for the subclasses to use:

```
public abstract class PageRenderer {
  protected A a;
  protected B b;
  protected C c;
  protected D d;
  Protected E e;
  //there might be even more instance variables
}
```

and all the subclasses of `PageRenderer` share these instance variables.

According to the conditions above, I would change the `PageRendererFactory` so that it contains the mentioned *instance variables*:

```
public class PageRendererFactory extends AbstractFactory {
  private A a;
  private B b;
  private C c;
  private D d;
  Private E e;
  //there might be even more instance variables here
  PageRenderer createPageRenderer(Type type) {
    //use the instance variables to instantiate the subclass of PageRenderer according to the Type
  }
}//Code AbstractFactory is skipped here
```

**Question: In this case, I probably need setters on this `PageRendererFactory`, but then this factory seems to be mixed with the *builder pattern*! So is this a good solution? or is there any better alternative for this solution?**

Comment: Who says you can't use the builder pattern together with the factory pattern?

Comment: no one says :D but it just looks a bit odd

Comment: I don't see any reason not to do this, so just create a builder!

Comment: What do you mean? I don't see your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You decision to use Factory is correct.**

And there doesn't matters, how this Factory will be created.

By direct call

```
Factory factory = new Factory();
```

By direct call with setters

```
Factory factory = new Factory();
factory.setA(a);
...
factory.setE(e);
```

By call with parameters

```
Factory factory = new Factory(a, b, c, d, e);
```

Or via builder

```
Factory factory = new Factory.Builder()
    .withA(a)
    ...
    .withE(e)
    .build();
```

Like for me, constructor with parameters is preferable because it prevents you from missing one or more internal fields.